# Evaluate $\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{10x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3}}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, alternative-proof

I'm trying to prove $$I=\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{10x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3}}dxdy=\frac83(\sqrt2-1)$$ in an elementary way.

**What I've tried**
I'm not satisfied with my following method.
Integrating w.r.t. $x$:
$$I=\int_0^1\left[-\frac{20}3 \left(y^{3/2}-\sqrt{y^3+1}\right)-y^{-3/2}\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{4}{3};-\frac{1}{y^3}\right)\right]dy$$
Integrating w.r.t. $y$:
$$I=\int_0^1\left(10 \sqrt x-x^{-3/2}\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{4}{3};-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)dx$$
Although I know how to handle some integrals of kind $\int_0^1x^\alpha(1-x)^\beta {}_pF_q(x)dx$ and how to cancel some "adjacent" hypergeometric function values, but concerning the answer and the integrand is so simple, I strongly believe that there are simple substitutions , IBPs, Feymann's tricks or something similar that can directly solve the integral. Any alternative solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ I=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{10x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3}}dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{10y^2-1}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3}}dxdy$$
$$\Rightarrow I=5\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3}}dxdy-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3}}dxdy$$
$$=10\int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3}}dxdy-2\int_0^1\int_0^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+y^3}}dxdy$$
$$\overset{x=ty}=10\int_0^1 y \sqrt y\int_0^1\frac{t^2+1}{\sqrt{t^3+1}}dtdy-2\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt y}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^3+1}}dtdy$$
$$=4\int_0^1 \frac{t^2+1}{\sqrt{t^3+1}}dt-4\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^3+1}}dt=4\int_0^1 \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^3+1}}dt$$
$$=\frac83\sqrt{t^3+1}\bigg|_0^1=\frac83\left(\sqrt 2-1\right)$$

Comment: How did you change the limit $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\stackrel{?}{\rightarrow}2\int_0^1\int_0^y$$ @Zacky

Comment: @Dr.Antidode If $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ (the integrand is a symmetric function) then:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)dxdy=2\int_0^1\int_0^y f(x,y)dxdy=2\int_0^1\int_y^1 f(x,y)dxdy$$
That is since for the first integral we are integrating over the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and for the other too integrals we split this square in half (over the diagonal) which produces two triangles, also since the function is symmetric the integral over the lower triangle is equal to the integral over the upper triangle and equal to half of the integral over the whole square.